# Inserting new row / note at the beginning of a sheet during XLSX Export

Tags: node.js, xlsx

I am new to node.js and I am able to write my data into workbook but I am  facing an issue with inserting a note at the beginning of my data.
Please note that the data is being fetched from DB but note is static or from session.

```
var export = XLSX.utils.json_to_sheet(this.obj);
    var wb = XLSX.utils.book_new() // make Workbook of Excel
    // add Worksheet to Workbook    
    XLSX.utils.book_append_sheet(wb, export, 'sheet1') // sheet1 is name of Worksheet  
    XLSX.utils.sheet_add_json(wb.Sheets.sheet1,
      [
        {note: "This is a note"},
      ],
      {
        header: ["note"],
        skipHeader:true,
        origin: "A1"
      }
    );
    // export Excel file
    XLSX.writeFile(wb, 'book.csv') // name of the file is 'book.xlsx'
```

here in the above code I am trying to add note using sheet_add_json but it is overwriting the existing data at A1. Though it works fine when tried with empty cell

Below is expected output in excel format.

This is a Note

```
Name    RollNo  Age
Abc      101    10
def      102    15
xyz      103    20
```

But As per the current code I am getting

```
This is a Note  RollNo  Age
Abc              101    10
def              102    15
xyz              103    20
```

Comment: you are saying it to start from A1 (origin: A1) and change it to "This is a note" which is what it is doing. Look at this https://www.npmjs.com/package/xlsx

Comment: yeah I want "This a note" in A1 and rest of the data like name, rollno and age should start from A2 or A3

Answer (score 1):

from the documentation "XLSX.utils.sheet_add_json takes an array of objects and updates an existing worksheet object. It follows the same process as json_to_sheet and accepts an options argument:" It will only update, or it can add as new row at the bottom, using origin: -1.

try this:

```
//create sheet with empty json/there might be other ways to do this
export = XLSX.utils.json_to_sheet({});

//start frm A2 here 
XLSX.utils.sheet_add_json(wb.Sheets.sheet1,
  [{
    Name: 'Abc',
    RollNo: 101,
    Age: 10
   },
   {
    Name: 'def',
    RollNo: 102,
    Age: 15
   },
   {
    Name: 'xyz',
    RollNo: 103,
    Age: 20
   }],
  {
    header: ["note"],
    skipHeader:true,
    origin: "A2"
  }
);

//then add ur txt
 XLSX.utils.sheet_add_json(wb.Sheets.sheet1,
  [
    {note: "This is a note"},
  ],
  {
    header: ["note"],
    skipHeader:true,
    origin: "A1"
  }
);
```

Answer (score 0):

I was facing the same issue, try below

```
   this.obj.unshift(
          {
            COL_1: "Note: your issue solved",
            COL_2: " ",
            COL_3: " "
          },
          {
            COL_1: "Column 1",
            COL_2: "Column 2",
            COL_3: "Column 3"
          }
        );

    XLSX.utils.json_to_sheet(this.obj,
              {
                skipHeader: true
              });
```